# XSD: Document-wide attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

Hey, I am having difficulties referring to a document-wide defined attribute. I am using the attribute inside of an element using the `ref` attribute the way I believe it should work. But when I try to validate my test XML file against it, I just get an error that the attribute was not defined.

If I replace the `ref`-attribute by an inline declaration, or even by an `attributeGroup` that contains just the attribute definition, then it magically works. Visual Studio's autocomplete suggests me to import the namespace again with some prefix and wants to use that prefix on the attribute, although the namespace itself is already imported as the default namespace (and is the only one to be used).

I have boiled down both my XML and my XSD files pretty much, so this is what is left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo xmlns="http://example.com/test" attr="xy" />
<!-- Visual Studio autocompletes to this, which works too:
<foo xmlns="http://example.com/test" a:attr="xy" xmlns:a="http://example.com/test" />
-->
```

And this is the scheme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://example.com/test" targetNamespace="http://example.com/test"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:attribute name="attr" type="xs:string" />

  <xs:attributeGroup name="attrGroup">
    <xs:attribute name="attr" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute ref="attr" />
      <!-- These two examples work:
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="attrGroup" />
      <xs:attribute name="attr" type="xs:string" />
      -->
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

What's the cause of this behaviour and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ref="attr"` is a reference to the top-level attribute declaration with `name="attr"`, which declares an attribute in the target namespace of the schema document. This isn't usually what you want, which is why top-level attribute declarations are rarely seen. It's better to reference the attribute group, which contains a local attribute named `"attr"`, which (because `attributeFormDefault` is implicitly unqualified) is in no namespace.

Comment: Ah, thank you. So per default attributes are not in any namespace?